How to fix dynamic heading with API first letter Capitalise in NextJs
Dynamic heading with API first letter to be Capitalised in NextJs
with Pagination count value change for text
this functionality using with Javascript not use in Css
error showing in this code
{${props.currentPath + " News"} ${props.renderPage ? '- Page ' + parseInt(props.renderPage + 1) : ''}}

Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Does this answer your question? How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?

The code snippet you provided has a syntax error. Try resolving that . You can solve like this -  {${props.currentPath.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + props.currentPath.slice(1)} News${props.renderPage ? ' - Page ' + (parseInt(props.renderPage) + 1) : ''}}

Using the variable of the top in  Next Js First letter Capitalize
Please try this code
let titleFirstLetter = props.currentPath;
let pageTitle = titleFirstLetter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + titleFirstLetter.slice(1);

{`${pageTitle + " News"} ${props.renderPage ? '- Page ' + parseInt(props.renderPage + 1) : ''}`}

